# Mongoose connection giving me error on random triggers in openshift

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, openshift

I have an error connecting in mongo
and it is happening after some triggers i.e may be on 1st or on 4th or more.

my connection with mongodb is

mongoose.js file

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose')

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

mongoose.connect('mongodb://user:password@mongodb/sampledb')

module.exports={mongoose}
```

[image]

The error log are like this

Error connecting to Mongo. Message:
MongoError: failed to connect to server [172.30.49.208:27017] on first connect [MongoError: connect EHOSTUNREACH 172.30.49.208:27017]
(node:36) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [mongodb:27017] on first connect [MongoNetworkError: connect EHOSTUNREACH 172.30.49.208:27017]
GET /pagecount 200 8.643 ms - 17

Comment: You don't need to export `mongoose` like that. NodeJS will `require` and actually load "once" only, no matter how many times you put that in your code. But is that the question? Seems like there should be more here than just a small block of code.

Comment: Please add more detail;i cant see img.

Comment: You may post a text form of your terminal output rather than a screenshot.